# App vuforia se cierra en android y es muy lenta

Tags: unity3d, vuforia

Tengo una aplicación de realidad aumentada, estoy usando **Unity 3D versión 5.3.3f1.**
La versión de **vuforia es 6.2.10.**

Los problemas son los siguientes:

- Se cierra al iniciar la aplicación
- A veces cuando carga, se cierra después de un tiempo de uso.

Estos problemas se presentan más en teléfonos viejos(gamas medias de hace 2 años más o menos), los teléfonos más recientes soportan mejor la app.

Por las pruebas que sea han realizado el origen del problema son los modelos 3D(formato fbx) los cuáles están en la escena de Unity, colocados sobre sus respectivos targets, ya que entre más pesado sea el archivo fbx o entre más modelos haya en escena es más probable que la aplicación se cierre o se alente.

Por ahora se ha reducido el tamaño de cada modelo 3D haciéndolos más sencillos y se ha logrado que la app funcione con más modelos que antes, sin embargo aún hay dispositivos  que no la soportan.

¿Hay alguna forma de reducir el tamaño de los archivos fbx, o alguna configuración que permita un mejor performance de la aplicación?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay muchas formas de reducir el tamaño de los fbx.
Desde usar retopologia y recrear tu modelo usando menos polígonos, usar plugins incluidos en los principales software 3d para la reducción automáticas de polígonos, o usar software especifico como [Polygon Cruncher](http://www.mootools.com/plugins/us/polygoncruncher/) o algún asset para LOD también puede valer ya que a fin de cuentas también reducen la malla del objeto.

Esto ya es una optimización del perfomance ya que reduciras dependiendo de tus modelos, el tamaño de los archivos y numero de polígonos a cargar. Liberando memoria para otras tareas.